# Wordpress, custom php site only available for logged in users

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and need to write some php-code that only users that are logged in are available to see. How can I do that?

Can I also use Worpress' MySQL connection or do I have to make my own? I have some custom tables in the same database that I need to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you didn't post any code with your question why not use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-private-site/

Comment: Thank you, that looks like something I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use WordPress functionality in a PHP file that exists outside of your WordPress installation then you need to include *wp-load.php*.

```
<?php include '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the line I was missing. Seems to get things working now!

Answer (score 0):

with wpdb you can perform any database operations. for custom tables as well as for wordpress' own tables.You dont have to see the database connection part.`global $wpdb` is sufficient for that